# Setting a collection through Expressions SSIS

Tags: ssis

I understand how to set simple type variables to the Expressions properties of a Task

I need help understanding, if it is possible, to set an Expression that is of type collection.

I have a custom Task that takes a parameter collection, that collection changes depending on which web method it tries to call
Example:
[image]

So how would I dynamically setup the correct collection, given I can properly identify the one to setup.

Answer (score 1):

What I infer is that  you have a custom task, it has a property and you want to set property value as of type collection, right?

You can create variable of type object which is used to store collection items. When you call web method, you can populate value of variable and you should assign this object variable to property.  So store parameter collections to string variable and then parse this string to a collection (object variable) in your custom task and assign this object variable to property.

If you are calling web method in your custom task then you can populate collection variable and assign to property value itself in task otherwise you need to add script component for populating those values.

Comment: Your first statement is correct.  I like your idea however I can not edit the custom task, I must use as is.